# Regular Expression to validate email address and allow only with .com and .asia

Tags: regex

I want to put a regular expression in the struts validation xml to validate email address which has .com or .asia enter by user. For example, to allow email address such as vinod@test.com and vinod@test.asia only. I tried a lot with following regular expression but still .asia is not working at all (.com is working) :-

Struts validator xml:-

```
<var><var-name>mask</var-name><var-value>^[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{2,4}~]+@[-!#$%&\'*+\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{2,4}~]+\.[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{2}|com|asia~]*$</var-value></var>
```

I changed the regular expressiont o following as well:-

```
^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_\+\.]*[a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\.]*[a-z0-9]\.(com|asia)|([0-9]{1,3}\.{3}[0-9]{1,3}))*$
```

But still it is not allowing email address with .asia?

Kindly advise.

Thank you

Comment: You put `com` and `asia` into a character class, put them into a grouping construct. Something like [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/lzqTXM/1). However, you might want to make the pattern less restrictive and use a mere `^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.(com|asia)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, why not just `^\S+@\S+\.(com|asia)$`? I dont think other whitespace characters are allowed in email addresses either

Comment: @vinod Kumar, whats with the `([0-9]{1,3}\.{3}[0-9]{1,3})` at the end? why do you also want to allow `123...456`?

Comment: `"Look at all these spaces!"@example.com` is a valid email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate a `.com` or `.asia` email address, just check that it looks like :

```
/.+@.+\.(com|asia)\z/
```

and send a [validation email](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

`"abc !$&*-=^|~#%'+/?_{} 123"@test.com`

is a valid email address.